# Cannot find PROCESSED_RES output for Main

Tags: android, android-studio

Getting this error while building android app bundle -

> Cannot find PROCESSED_RES output for Main{type=MAIN, fullName=debug,
>   filters=[], versionCode=-1, versionName=null}

I have just added a dynamic feature module in existing android studio project, Getting this error while building android app bundle

Comment: I had the same issue. And my app had abiSplit. I disabled it and it worked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56542195/java-io-ioexception-cannot-find-processed-res-output-for-main-dynamic-feature

Answer (score -2):

change versionName and versionCode increment with every release

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.company.app"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 14       // increment with every release
    versionName '1.4.8'   // change with every release

}
```

}

Comment: try this android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.outputFile = new File(
                    output.outputFile.parent,
                    output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-${variant.versionName}.apk"))
        }
    }
}

Comment: still not working, can you please explain me the meaning of this error

Comment: The "out" folder in the processed resources directory is empty for the feature module's build directory.This one is for issues with the sample

Comment: what happens? are you try run code any other person or github project so raise this error if yes then mark this answer as right answer

Comment: I am not running  any other person code or github project, but like I mentioned in my problem statment I have added a dynamic feature module in existing android studio project, Getting this error while building android app bundle