# java.io.IOException: Cannot find PROCESSED_RES output for Main [Dynamic Feature Module]

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dynamic

Adding a dynamic module into multi module project that already has 6 flavours.

Got this error,

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':dynMod@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :app.
Show Details
Affected Modules: dynMod
```

Created similar product flavours in dynamic module solved the issue. I did actually take builds and tested. Now not sure what went wrong but i'm getting this,

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot find PROCESSED_RES output for Main{type=MAIN, fullName=flavor1Debug, filters=[], versionCode=-1, versionName=null}
```

Can anyone help, please.

Answer (score 8):

The project had abiSplit configuration. Disabling it solved the issue.

```
//    splits {
//        abi {
//            enable true
//            universalApk true
//        }
//    }
```

Comment: In my case, I need this split option, any other way?