# How to fix 'Cannot find PROCESSED_RES output' error when using Dynamic Feature with Multiple APKs?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dynamic-feature-module

Error with Dynamic Feature and multiple APKs

I am using Splits to generate multiple APKs , now when i tried to introduce Dynamic feature getting following error

> Cannot find PROCESSED_RES output for SerializedForm(versionCode=18, versionName=2.3.3, variantOutputConfiguration=VariantOutputConfigurationImpl(isUniversal=false, filters=[]), baseName=worldDebug, fullName=worldDebug, outputFileName=world-worldDebug.apk)

**Note:** if i commented the Splits part its working fine as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56542195/java-io-ioexception-cannot-find-processed-res-output-for-main-dynamic-feature).